# How do i get rid of this annoying line at the end of the QTabWidget

Tags: python, css, qt, pyside, qtabbar

So i have a fairly simple style sheet to change the look of the tabs in my Qt app (i'm using PySide, but it shouldn't make much, if any, difference); here it is:

```
QWidget{
    background: gray;
}

QTabBar{
    background: gray;
}

QTabBar::tab {
    background: lightgray;
    padding: 10 10 5 10;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:  gray;
}

QTabBar::tab:selected {
    background:  gray;
    color: white;
}
```

If i just use this; then I get an ugly line at the end of the tab - like this: (this is the top right corner of the app - if you resize it so that it goes beyond the size of the tabs)

[image]

If i add the following CSS to the style sheet:

```
QTabWidget::pane{
}
```

i get this:

[image]

which may look like it fixes the problem, but it does not -

here is the same against a different coloured background:

[image]

I then thought that perhaps it was the other `lightgray` color in use, which would be better, since i want that part to be `lightgray` anyway, so I changed the colour of the `QTabBar` background to `lightgray`.

[image]

Still no success.

The colour of the line is neither `gray` nor `lightgray`, yet those are the only two colours I use.

**How do I get rid of this line?**

I would rather a style sheet solution, to keep it out of the program initialisation - as that seems like a messy solution.

Edit: this is using qt designer, and qt 4.6.2. I cannot upgrade the qt version easily.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your issue. Can you post a full code with the problem?

Comment: @Avaris that might not be so easy, the designer spits out a lot of stuff. And besides, i can get the issue in just the designer alone. Make a new `MainWindow` app, add a `QTabWidget` in a `QVerticalLayout` and then add the css to the `QMainWindow`. It will be harder to see with the frame on.

Comment: I still can't replicate it. [Here is](http://i.imgur.com/r4ktL.png) what i get. I put the `QLabel` above in order to not miss anything on the top.

Comment: What the?! What Qt version are you using? Could the fact that i'm on Scientific Linux have an effect?

Comment: Maybe the version difference has an effect. I'm using 4.8.0.

Comment: I'll try it out on another computer later then i guess